# How to define button in one class and define listener in diffrent class?

Tags: java

I have two classes in java: GLA14.java and NewFrame2.java. NewFrame2.java has a "SUBMIT" button. I want to define its listener in GLA14.java. How can I do this?

Comment: Why do you want to do something like this? Generally we create a listener as an independent class and use it to handle the actions.

Comment: As @Aakash said, or rather extract your listener out of `GLA14.java` if it already exists, and make it its own class (or even interface that some class in `GLA14` and some class in `NewFrame2` can implement).

Comment: I have a large set of private data members and member functions. I want to perform some operation on submit button which uses these data members and member functions.That's why I would like to define the actionPerformed() in GLA14.java.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't seems like a good idea, as Aakash suggest, you should create a  ListenerClass.java  and use it both GLA14.java and NewFrame2.java.
You can also try to write a public getter of the listener in GLA14.java.

Hope helped you!

Answer (score 1):

You could have a method in `NewFrame2` which takes in an `ActionListener` object as parameter. Within the body of this method within `NewFrame2`, you then assign it to the button:

```
public class NewFrame2 {
    ...
    public void assignEventHandler(ActionListener listener) {
        this.button.addActionListener(listener);
    }
    ...
}
```

In your GLA14:

```
...
Frame2 f2 = ...
f2.assignEventHandler(new EvtHlr());
...
```

Some other class (which will do the actual event handling):

```
public class EvtHlr implements ActionListener() {
    ...
}
```

That being said, what you are trying is unconventional. What is usually done is that you have either:

1. An anonymous class which will handle the event, declared within the same class where the button is declared.      OR
2. A seperate class (which implements ActionListener) which is accessible by the same class where the button is declared which is then passed as the button's event handler.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with a public method in the frame class

```
public class NewFrame extends JFrame {

private JButton button; 
public  Solution() {
    button= new JButton("Test");
    Container contentPane = getContentPane();
    contentPane.add(button);

}

public void associateListener(ActionListener o) {
    button.addActionListener((ActionListener) o);
}
```

}

And have a seperate action Listener class like below

```
public class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
System.out.println("Working Action Listener");
}
```

}

Attach these two with your GLA14 class like below

```
public class GLA14 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
Solution sol = new Solution();

sol.show();

sol.associateListener(new MyActionListener());
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Here is a woring example. Instantiation is a bit crappy, but you should get the idea.

GLA14.java:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class GLA14 implements ActionListener
{    
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
       new GLA14();
    }

    public GLA14()
    {
        new NewFrame2(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
    {
        System.out.println("Action Performed");        
    }
}
```

NewFrame2.java:

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class NewFrame2
{

    public NewFrame2(GLA14 gla14)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JButton submit = new JButton();
        frame.setBounds(10,10,200,100);
        frame.add(submit);

        submit.setText("Submit");
        submit.addActionListener(gla14);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Notice that the instance of GLA14 is passed as an argument to the constructor of NewFrame2. You can then assign the instance as ActionListener for the button.

Answer (score 1):

I simply defined a function calculate() in GLA14.java and in actionPerformed() of "SUBMIT" button in NewFrame2.java, I created an object of GLA14.java class and called calculate().
Thanks all for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can inherit or implement the listener in GLA14 and use the `setOnClickListener(new GLA14());` method of the button to use it.

Comment: I don't think this question relates to android